# Function to add 3 rows together in OpenOffice Calc then drag function down for 195,000 rows

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with 195,000 rows, There are 3 columns with different numbers in in the 4th column (D1) I enter `=A1+B1+C1` and it comes up with the answer, But I can only drag down the `AutoSum` feature slowly.

Is there a way to automate it so I can have the `Autosum` for all columns in D so it'd be `D1 : D195000`?

Comment: Wow, `Calc` sure makes an inconvenient database, eh? Perhaps you should look at [OO Base](https://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html).

Comment: To highlight any arbitrary range you can type a range into the name box (to the left of the formula bar) then hit enter.

Comment: @msw: you sure haven't tried (internal DB engine) Base with more than 100k rows. Besides from the learning curve of getting results in Base, it's pretty ugly slow, compared to a 3-column, 195k row Calc spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple trick you can do: Write your type on the first cell (`D1`) and anything to the last one (`D198K` - use the Navigator tool (F5) to go there fast). Then, copy the cell from the first cell, and press `Ctrl + Shift + End` (selection till the last cell that contains data) and then make a Paste.

This should paste the type to the selected shells, applying the type in analogy to each cell - unless you have used `$` in the type for a cell row and/or column, in order to preserve a cell.

You could simply follow this logic in order to create your own function in OpenOffice Calc.